# Dask computations slow down with time

Tags: python, docker, dask, dask-distributed

I'm having the following issue with Dask. I noticed that the same computations take longer and longer as time passes. After I restart scheduler, the computations are fast again, and just keep slowing down. The figure below shows the time consumed by my computations (I run them in a loop. The wider white spaces come from the fact that I run the loop a couple of times with breaks between them). I also noticed that the CPU usage of each worker goes down with time.

[image: Time consumed by each iteration is continuously growing]

When I look at Dask dashboard, I see that CPU consumption by workers goes down with time - it starts with usually 90-100% in the first iterations and ends with 0-20% in last ones. Also the task stream seems much sparser in late iterations:
[image: Task streams in early iterations vs late iterations]

## Reproducible example

I use dask container `daskdev/dask-notebook` (Python 3.8, dask 2021.4.0, dask-core 2021.4.0, distributed 2021.4.0, numpy 1.18.1, h5py 3.2.1). In that container I run 2 jupyter notebooks - one for running scheduler, and the other for running computations.

### Prepare data

In one of the notebooks run the following to create data.

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np
path = "/home/jovyan/data.h5" 
x = np.random.randint(0, 2**15, size=(4096, 150000), dtype=np.int16)
with h5py.File(path, "w") as f:
    f.create_dataset("/x", data=x, chunks=(32, 150000))
```

### Run computations

In notebook 1 start the scheduler:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
c = Client()
c
```

My machine has 4 cores (8 threads) and 16GB ram, so this creates 4 workers with 2 threads and 3.8GB ram each.

In notebook 2 connect to that scheduler:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client

address = "127.0.0.1:38835"  # port based on output from notebook 1
c = Client(address, set_as_default=True)
```

and benchmark simple computation (load integers from disk, then compute fft on partitions, take absolute value, and finally sum over one of the axes):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import gc
import numpy as np
import h5py
import dask.array as da


def process(path):
    f = h5py.File(path) 
    d = f['/x'] 
    darr = da.from_array(d, chunks=d.chunks)
    mapped = darr.map_blocks(np.fft.fft)
    absolute = da.absolute(mapped)
    reduced = absolute.mean(axis=-1)
    return reduced.compute()


n_iterations = 20
log_file = "benchmark.csv"
delay_between_iterations = 5 
path = "/home/jovyan/data.h5" 

with open(log_file, "w") as file:
    file.write("StartTime,ExecTime\n")

for i in range(n_iterations):
    print(f"{i+1}th iteration")
    gc.collect()
    start = datetime.now()
    process(path)
    end = datetime.now()
    exec_time = (end - start).total_seconds()
    with open(log_file, "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{start},{exec_time}\n")
    sleep(delay_between_iterations)
```

The generated csv file is plotted above, in the beginning of this post.

### Emitted warning messages

After I come back to the notebook 1 (with scheduler started) and stop scheduler `c.close()` I see a bunch of warnings:

> distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 41% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
> distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 41% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
> distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 41% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
> distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 42% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)

Then, when I restart, still in notebook 1, `c = Client()`, I see some warnings as below, and more of them appearing as computations in notebook 2 run.

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bokeh/application/application.py:146: RuntimeWarning: coroutine '_needs_document_lock.._needs_document_lock_wrapper' was never awaited
> static_paths = {h.static_path() for h in self.handlers}
> Task was destroyed but it is pending!
> task: <Task pending name='Task-27802557' coro=<_needs_document_lock.._needs_document_lock_wrapper() running at /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bokeh/server/session.py:51> cb=[multi_future..callback() at /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py:520]>
> Task was destroyed but it is pending!
> task: <Task pending name='Task-27802558' coro=<_needs_document_lock.._needs_document_lock_wrapper() running at /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bokeh/server/session.py:51> cb=[multi_future..callback() at /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py:520]>

Additionally after executing some code in Notebook 1 (with scheduler), I keep getting warnings below previously run cell:

> distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 43% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
> distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 43% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
> distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 43% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)

## Summary

My main problem is that the computations slow down. The emitted warnings may just be useful as a clues.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Possibly related post:
[Dask: why has CPU usage suddenly dropped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707190/dask-why-has-cpu-usage-suddenly-dropped)

Answer (score 1):

After performing some experiments I noticed that the problem was not in Dask, but it seems to be in Docker.

I tried running the code without Docker, just in venv on my system (Manjaro). The problem did not occur in that case.

A hypothesis: maybe the problem is somewhere in docker's network. This explains why the CPU consumption goes down - Dask is just waiting for tasks and has nothing to do for most of the time. Although I don't have enough knowledge to diagnose the issue precisely.